# iOS: How to set custom thumbnail image to AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have an AVPlayer that plays video from a remote URL. a thumbnail image is set automatically when it is paused. but this takes some time. is there a way to set a custom image like a placeholder for the thumbnail image? I've tried the following but it didn't work.

```
videoPlaceholderImageView = UIImageView(frame: (avPlayerViewConroller?.contentOverlayView?.frame)!)
videoPlaceholderImageView.image = videoPlaceholderImage
avPlayerViewConroller?.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(videoPlaceholderImageView)
```